# Can't omit outline with combo box

Tags: css, sapui5, outline

I've just started to work with SAPUI5, and I'm having some trouble regarding combo boxes.

When I open the new window I created, it starts focusing the combo box, but with an annoying dotted outline. It only disappears if I click outside the combo box, but I really need it to not show at all, not even when I click inside.

I have tried several libs and classes, but none of these gave me the desired output.

Below are the classes I tried:

```
.comboCreateDoc {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    outline: 0px transparent !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
}

html.sap-desktop .comboCreateDoc .sapMInputBaseContentWrapper {
    border: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    outline-style: none !important;
    outline: 0px dotted transparent !important;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}

html.sap-desktop .sapMBtn:focus > .sapMFocusable {
    outline: 0px dotted transparent !important;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}

html.sap-desktop .sapMCbBgs:active > .sapMFocusable {
    outline: 0px dotted transparent !important;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}

.sapMInputBaseIconContainer{    
    outline: none !important;
}

.sapMComboBoxInner .sapMInputBaseInner{    
    outline: none !important;    
}


html.sap-desktop .sapUiBody:focus {
    outline: non !important;    
}
```

How can I make the dotted outline disappear?

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the dotted outline is there for a reason — accessibility. I highly recommend you don't remove it.

Comment: For other readers: Discussion whether outline should be displayed at all in UI5 can be seen here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1289

Answer (score 0):

I dig into their samples to find the combo box and I saw that they don't use the native browser focus.
They put a class `.sapMFocus` that gives that dotted border to the element.

You need to override that class styles like that:

```
.sapMFocus .sapMInputBaseContentWrapper::before {
 border:none;
}
```